# How to close a com.codename1.io.Socket after Socket.connect

Tags: codenameone

I have successfully connected to my Server, wrote our CMD and received the expected response. Now I want to close this Socket. I do not see a close method in the Socket class. Here is the code snippet for connecting, write and read CMD/Response.
    Socket.connect(host.getText(), Port, new SocketConnection()

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just close the streams and return from the method to close the socket as the connection remains open as long as the method is running.